# Is it possible to negate an element from receiving display:none using the :not pseudo-class in CSS?

Tags: css, pseudo-class, negation

```
<html>
<body>
<nav>....</nav>
<article>more things...</article>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">contents</div>
<body>
</html>
```

In linked CSS file (using Chrome):

```
@media print{
body:not(#myModal){
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#myModal{ /*shouldn't have to but doesn't work anyway */
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
}
}
```

This does not work.  I am trying to get rid of everything behind the modal for printing without scripting.  Apparently that is not possible.  Can a display:none :not not negate elements contained within the container?

Edit:  I have looked here, but cannot find the answer.  https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

Edit:  I want to hide everything except the modal.  But display:none keeps that from happening.  It does it for the whole body element, regardless of my negation.

Edit:  Whatever it is, it does not work in the media call, so my current idea is to move the div.  I thought there might be a better way.  Edit:  I also need display:none because print will still print the blank pages where the elements are hidden.  display will remove those elements and allow me to print my modal without a bunch of blank pages of hidden elements.

Comment: `div:not(#myModal){` perhaps

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this? Do you want to hide the container within the body element or something else?

Comment: Regarding performance `body > *:not(#myModal)` ... https://jsfiddle.net/85ruoa1v/

Comment: @DaniP The problem is not that not doesn't work.  It doesn't work using display:none.

Comment: @DaniP Great minds thinking alike!

Comment: The problem is the selector doesn't work because you are hidding all the body like "all body elements except the one with id mymodal" but really you need all descendants of body except **mymodal**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: none` doesn't load the element or it's children. To Chrome, Firefox, etc., `#myModal` doesn't exist. Consequently, you can't use `display: none` as the way to did.

There are other alternatives though:

### Option 1

```css
@media print {

    * {
       visibility: hidden;
       height: 0 !important; /* added !important with info from update */
    }

    #myModal {
        visibility: visible;
        height: auto !important;
    }

}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>....</nav>
<article>more things...</article>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">contents</div>
<button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
<body>
```

### Option 2

 This probably won't work with your new update.

```css
@media print {
    body > *:not(#myModal) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>....</nav>
<article>more things...</article>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">contents</div>
<button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
<body>
```

Comment: The CSS does not with the media call @media print, so maybe it is something special there.  I believe the statement is correct, but the CSS did not affect anything.  I will need to move the div for printing out of the body element temporarily via scripting, best I can tell so far.  Thanks.

Comment: I marked it answered because your example works.  Something else is wrong with mine evidently.  Must be because it is modal.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it working.  It was some naming issues.

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)